# A seemingly random sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Take the function $f(x,n)=\frac{10^x-1}{9}$ $mod$ $n$
and the sequence $s_n$ that follows these rules:

1. $x$ is an integer counting up from 1
2. If $f(x,n)$ repeats at some point, $s_n$ is equal to how long the loop is (For the 3. sequence $[1,2,3,4,3,4,3...]$ this number would be 2)
3. If $f(x,n)$ stops (loops a number), $s_n$ is equal to how long it takes to stop.

If you do this, you get the sequence $[0,0,3,1,0,3,6,2,9,0,2,3,12,6,3,3...]$
which is seemingly random.

My question is,
Is there an infinite number of $0$'s in this sequence?

Comment: I think it's a coincidence, but as far as you've computed, the $0$s are at the perfect squares. What happens at $16$ (the next value)? What happens in other bases, replacing $10$ by $b$ and $9$ by $b-1$?

Comment: I started counting at $0$. Still worth checking the next value.

Comment: If I understand the setup correctly, the $0$ at $10$ is the last one. In order to stop immediately, we need a factor of $10$.

Comment: @EthanBolker *x^2+1 anyways $s_16=3$ and $s_17=16$ (I clicked add comment too early)

Comment: Two-digit (and in general, multiple-symbol) subscripts need curly braces: `$s_{16}$` yields $s_{16}$.

Comment: Do see what happens with other bases $b$. [edit] results into the question, don't put them in comments.

Comment: OP: to clarify, is a $0$ obtained precisely when $f(1,n)=f(2,n)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integers $n$ for which $\frac{10^2-1}9\mod n = \frac{10^1-1}9\mod n$ are precisely the divisors of $10$ (and thus the OP found them all). Note that this equality is equivalent to each of
\begin{align*}
\frac{10^2-1}9 &\equiv \frac{10^1-1}9 \pmod n \\
\frac{10^2-1}9 - \frac{10^1-1}9 &\equiv 0 \pmod n \\
10 &\equiv 0 \pmod n,
\end{align*}
and the last congruence is true (by definition) exactly when $n\mid 10$.

Remark 1: If $10$ and $9$ are replaced by $b$ and $b-1$, respectively, the same argument shows that the answer is all divisors of $b$.

Remark 2: This is one of many examples why (in my opinion) looking at the *relation* $a\equiv b\pmod n$ is much more helpful than looking at the *function* $a\mod n$.

Remark 3: Without framing the relationships among the values of $f(x,n)$ in terms of congruences, it's not even clear that the repeating patterns must always continue—nor is it even clear that once a value repeats, it must keep repeating!